# TinyMCE editor in wp_editor is removing my html tags

Tags: wordpress, editor, tinymce, html

How can i set the tinyMCE editor in wp_editor to not modify/replace the html tags of the initial content ?

I'm loading html content with < b > tags (i know that they are deprecated but i need them) and the tinyMCE editor is replacing them.

I tried several things but with no success. I'm getting a little frustrated. I need help.

What i need is that the editor do not change the loaded html content.

Sorry for my bad english! It's not my native language.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like tinymce stripps some html tags out, which tinymce does not recognize as "valid".
You will need to set your tinymce config to keep those html elements (make them valid).

There are the following tinymce settings for this:

- [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children) (defines which html elements are valid + valid attributes)
- [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) (defines which combinations of parent and child elements are valid)

Comment: Yes, but where i set up this parameters? i'm passing an array with options to the wp_editor() method. But it doesn't work.

Comment: there are some examples to be found on this page: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48356/creating-a-wp-editor-instance-with-custom-tinymce-buttons

Comment: There is some way that the editor does not change at all my content?

Comment: this was possible in pretty old versions of tinymce where you could set cleanup:false. but i think this no longer works and the cleanup gets done no matter what

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll keep looking for another solution to my problem! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

just change the attributes to

```
    valid_children : "+a[div|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|#text]", (defines which html elements are valid + valid attributes)
    valid_elements : '*[*]', (defines which combinations of parent and child elements are valid)
```